# Should there be a higher standard for moderating election-related content?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-election, moderators, code-of-conduct

I came across this thread (now deleted), *https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399436/why-was-this-comment-chain-removed-from-the-moderator-questionnaire/399460*, about a chain of comments removed by a moderator under the *"Community Moderator Election - Questionnaire"* post. There were also a bunch of my comments, unrelated to the chain mentioned in the other thread, which were removed.

While I mainly agree with Cody's points, I believe there are different opinions among moderators (e.g. there is another answer by a moderator for which I cannot say the same as what I said about Cody's) which need to be discussed in the context of an election.

A democratic process needs transparency and I don't think our community election is different. The main structure of the process is very clear and I, personally, don't see any major issues. But deleting some information in the midst of an election is worrying.

I surely believe that CoC should be applied here as well and any insult, bigotry, or false information should not be tolerated. But there is a fine line between criticism and insult. I understand that on the main site and even on the meta (when the election is not discussed) we try to steer clear of personal issues and criticizing one's actions, if not directly related to SO. But obviously, an election is different. We need to make sure that a nominee is worthy of our vote and will act in the community's best interest. We need to make sure they have the qualities expected as listed on the election page and that's mainly possible through discussion and constructive criticism, which sometimes may touch previous actions.

> - patient and fair
> - leads by example
> - shows respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words
> - open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track, and resolve uncommon disputes and exceptions

I want to ask the community and specially the moderators to clarify/explain their point of view on ***Election Content Moderation*** so we can reach a standard that the majority of the community agrees with.

Comment: "a fine line between criticism and insult" <<-- An insult is an insult. Look at it for what it is. (If someone can't formulate a critique that's unambiguously respectful, the best course of action is deleting it and let someone else try.)

Comment: @bad_coder "An insult is an insult" = "a fine line between criticism and insult". That's exactly what I said. In **most** of those deleted comments (I haven't seen them all, so that's that) I haven't seen any insult. In my comments, I am sure that there were nothing that can be considered an insult. Even the OP which I was discussing with said (at the end) that it's all good. Would you clarify on your comment? I am not sure if I get your point. Cheers.

Comment: I think my previous answer goes a long way towards what I think should be the general policy. There *does* have to be a higher standard for moderators when moderating election-related content, in order to preserve trust on such a sensitive issue where there is almost no transparency. Stuff that would normally be inappropriate in a comment (like questioning a person's behavior) *has* to become permissible during an election, because that's the whole point of an election. I'm not sure what else needs to be said here. I could write another long answer if you like... :-)

Comment: @Cody you already know my answer, I love your rants <3. For starters, they're not rants. You put all kind of useful tips and points in there. If you care to do so, I'd appreciate it. That would start a discussion which I suppose can be beneficial. I just want to point out that I am not expecting moderators to discuss what they usually discuss in the mod rooms here; but some sort of clarification/discussion would benefit the community.

Comment: Personally I would move such comments to chat unless they're absolutely/clearly against CoC.... best of both worlds. Unfortunately, mods currently can only move comments to chat once. So I would also be lighting a fire under devs to allow repeated 'move to chat' options for comment threads until they come up with their full replacement for the "comments under questions" paradigm.

Comment: @TylerH by such comments you mean extensive discussions on these topics or just anything that is touching personal actions, even if it is limited to couple comments?

Comment: @CodyGray just another question. Is it ok if one posts a question about such behaviors? Like if someone post a question asking a nominee why they have supported a certain SO employee. (I tried to make a hypothetical example, no puns intended).

Comment: I would not do it as a separate question, no. Election questions to the nominees need to be kept contained as much as possible. *Maybe* next election cycle we could look into having a generic community-wiki Q&A on Meta for the community to ask questions to the candidates as questions, and the candidate respond in comments? Dunno. Note that for the next election, the election tooling will have been revamped, so predicting now what we'll have is a bit premature.

Comment: @M-- I mean any extensive discussion that makes it difficult to utilize the page otherwise.

Comment: @CodyGray The thread is now deleted, so is your answer. Would you post a copy here so everyone can see your input (not just 10k+ users). There will be minimal edits to keep the content specifically related to that incident out. I could do it and make it a wiki but I don't it's the right thing to do. Thank you and sorry for dragging you from one post to another :D

Comment: On another note, why that one is deleted. Comments were removed and now the discussion about the removal is gone. I am deeply concerned about these actions. @SamuelLiew would you illustrate on that? Thank you.

Comment: Deleted comments have been restored on the previous questionnaire thread.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I know. Still something has happened, it has been disputed, and then reversed. Why the trace of that should be removed?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Moreover, post was close as "Not suitable for this site" which does not make any sense to me. If we cannot question moderators' actions on Meta, then where?

Comment: `it has been disputed, and then reversed. Why the trace of that should be removed?` Yes, I found that concerning too but I guessed that thread might have been removed to avoid further flame wars and further arguments.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I just want to mention one more thing about the **restored comments**. They have been restored on a **deleted post**.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl [Should there be a higher standard for moderating election-related content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352519) If you're interested.

Comment: @CodyGray ^^ I quoted you here. If I draw any conclusions that are different from what you meant, please point them out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't really had time to go back and revisit this, and don't really have the energy to post another answer. I don't think the original question should have been deleted, but I'm hesitant to unilaterally override another moderator. I have no problem with you quoting me, as long as it's an actual quote. Nothing there is a secret. Feel free to link to the original Q&A, as it's still visible to 10k+ users.

Comment: @CodyGray I am really glad to have an impartial and responsive moderator like you. I will be sad if/when you will leave the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am copying some parts of [my question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352519/should-there-be-a-higher-standard-for-moderating-election-related-content), mostly quoting Cody Gray, to preserve that post which is now [deleted here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399460/6461462). There is some duplicate info between my question and answer in favor of coherence.

---

---

#### What has happened:

After some discussion, the decision of removing those comments was reversed and comments were restored. But then the post itself was deleted by a CM. I am not against removing that post since it no longer serves any purpose as the nominee decided to leave the network. But removing the other thread which was talking about moderation of the post and deleting comments concerns me.

#### My suggestions:

I suggest posting another thread documenting the general aspects of the incident if moderator team thinks that there is more harm than good in keeping the thread. But the trace of all those actions should not be removed altogether so it can be used as a reference later.

In general, I also think it is not a bad idea for moderators to post a comment explaining what has been removed (a summary of the matter) and instructing users on what to do, e.g. saying that this topic should not be discussed anymore for reasons A & B. This is not required in so many cases, but if there is an ongoing discussion about the matter, I think that would help a lot. However, deleting comments should be the last resort when an election is involved.

---

I mainly agree with *[Cody Gray's points about what should be done when moderating election-related content (on the deleted thread)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399460/6461462)*. I am quoting parts of their answer here:

> I deferred answering this Meta question or doing anything about it
> until after I could discuss it privately with the moderator who made
> the original decision. After doing so, it seems we are not going to
> see eye-to-eye on this issue. I am not going to overrule that
> moderator's decision (if only for practical reasons, because it simply
> doesn't make sense to have a moderator deletion-undeletion war), but I
> cannot in good conscience just stay quiet about this.

There are different opinions among moderators about some actions. **Of course there is nothing wrong with that in general.** Usually, those differences should be discussed within mod rooms and a decision can be reached. But election-related content has a higher stake, so, there should be a higher standard as well. I think community's opinion should be *considered* in moderating election-related content. It doesn't mean that everything should be shared with the community but some more transparency is needed. For instance, moderator who has deleted the comments has not posted a comment saying that they were removed and explaining why, as if there was never a discussion on that topic. That can arise to be considered *censorship* when an election is in place.

> deleting comments critical of a candidate during an election is
> extremely dangerous and should be avoided at nearly all costs because
> of the danger of appearance of bias towards/against a particular
> candidate.

Again, I surely believe that CoC should be applied always and any insult, bigotry, or false information should not be tolerated. But during an election it should be applied with a greater care. Sometimes I, myself, may flag a comment which can cause some heat, but if it is an election, I would not make that decision as easily as other times.

> The community needs to be able to ask questions, many of them
> difficult, about their candidates. This is key to a legitimate
> democratic election, and it is absolutely necessary on Stack Overflow,
> where an extremely high level of trust is placed by the community in
> their moderators. Moderator candidates need to be able to withstand
> being asked and be willing to answer difficult questions to the
> community's satisfaction. That entire process is subverted if such
> comments are deleted. Asking questions is not "harassment"—it's the
> process.

My main concern here is about transparency. Again, [Cody phrased it perfectly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399562/should-there-be-a-higher-standard-for-moderating-election-related-content#comment783712_399562):

> There does have to be a higher standard for moderators when moderating
> election-related content, in order to preserve trust on such a
> sensitive issue where there is almost no transparency. Stuff that
> would normally be inappropriate in a comment (like questioning a
> person's behavior) has to become permissible during an election,
> because that's the whole point of an election.

---

---

---

Adding Cody's *"full"* answer with some redaction (as they were directly related to the incident):

> [REDACTED]
>
> {REDACTED}. But even if there wasn't bias involved in the decision,
> **deleting comments critical of a candidate during an election is extremely dangerous and should be avoided at nearly all costs because
> of the danger of appearance of bias towards/against a particular
> candidate.**
>
> Even if there was no impropriety whatsoever, the handling of this
> situation creates the illusion of impropriety, which is highly
> problematic in my eyes.
>
> The community needs to be able to ask questions, many of them
> difficult, about their candidates. This is key to a legitimate
> democratic election, and it is absolutely necessary on Stack Overflow,
> where an extremely high level of trust is placed by the community in
> their moderators. Moderator candidates need to be able to withstand
> being asked and be willing to answer difficult questions to the
> community's satisfaction. That entire process is subverted if such
> comments are deleted. **Asking questions is not "harassment"—it's the
> process.**
>
> I have, on a couple of occasions, deleted comments underneath
> nomination posts that say little more than, "I will vote for you!" or
> "Good luck!", because these provide no real useful information. On the
> contrary, comments that level a specific criticism are useful,
> regardless of one's personal feelings about the candidate and/or about
> that criticism. If nothing else, others may have the same question,
> and it's better to give the candidate a chance to answer those
> allegations once, rather than have the conversation over and over.
>
> More drama and mistrust is the last thing that Stack Overflow needs.
>
> Putting aside whether or not it is justifiable or consistent with
> one's prior words/actions, (REDACTED) is a massive violation of trust,
> just as it would be to change anything you publicly stand for. So is
> supporting the removal of comments that are critical of you. Worse
> than all of that is posting an answer that accuses other users
> (REDACTED) and other serious allegations without any
> legitimate proffer of evidence. {REDACTED}.
>
> [REDACTED]