Shouldn't we enforce the few existing rules for Collectives?
Right now we have few rules (beyond the enforceable SO rules) specific to each Collective (for instance, rules for RM selection within r-collective).
In the case of the CI/CD Collective, there are even fewer rules for Recognized Members (RMs), as shown in the following screenshot from SOfT Collectives Launchpad.*

In a recent incident, one of the recognized members in CI/CD has been suspended for a week, and hence, is not eligible under these rules to maintain their RM status. However, they have not lost their status a month after the suspension. It was also brought to my attention that there was another case of suspension involving a Collective's RM without any effect on their RM status (I am/was not aware of that case as it did not make the "news").
As I stated in a previous post, I reckon that having an RM badge is an unnecessary addition/noise. But putting that aside, I do believe that we need to enforce the very limited number of rules specific to Collectives. Otherwise, it'll be a slippery slope and Collectives will be deviating from rules, general or specific, down the road (which I believe should be minimized).
Please share your thoughts on the appropriate course of actions. How can we make sure that these rules are not ignored?

* Upon my previous inquiries, it's been clarified that unless the materials are explicitly marked/identified as private, we can share them with community as needed. 

In this particular instance, it has been escalated. However, CMs are understaffed and overworked, so it's going to take a while. This isn't about lacking enforcement, it's just that things take time - there isn't really anything to discuss yet

@Zoe Thanks for the update. I am aware of the escalation (by Dalija) and have received an update from CM team as well, but figured there should be a thread for future reference.

For future reference about one very specific case? I don't see how that's productive

"For future reference rules should be enforced" is kinda weird

@Zoe I like to keep tabs on incidents that can recur: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399562/should-there-be-a-higher-standard-for-moderating-election-related-content and not that specific. I will have a follow up on r-collective rules in a couple of months :)

@KevinB well they haven't been immediately (or at least what I'd consider reasonable timeframe) enforced. We're living in weird times.

That's, again, because CMs are understaffed and overworked, and are the only ones with access to remove recognised members. It's not great, but unless you can pull more CMs out of thin air, there's nothing to do but wait

@Zoe I have 2 objectives: 1) I wanted to document the rules (previously hidden behind SOfT instance) and the incident to set a precedent for future similar issues. That helps to ask for handling future possible cases without the need to escalate (and discuss in TL). 2) To try and speed things up. But that's only the secondary intent. And as you said, it may not be possible. -- but I will be happy with accomplishing only the first one.

@Zoe I also forgot to ask; how is this "one very specific case"? An RM violated the rules and got suspended which then means they are not eligible for the status anymore. That can happen for number of reasons, not just violating the temp policy.

That case is indeed not the only one in which a Collective RM was suspended (mod-only link to example in another Collective). It would be good to 1) clarify what the existing rules are, 2) have one unified set of rules across all Collectives for when RM status is removed. Under the existing rules, it isn't clear that a suspension results in removal of current RM status, much as while people with recent suspensions on the network cannot be elected as mods, a suspension on another site doesn't (inherently) result in removal of current mod status.

@M-- As currently written, the main focus is "why wasn't this particular user removed when ?". The answer is "because no CMs have reviewed this yet". CMs aren't saying it shouldn't be enforced (because, again, they haven't reviewed the case yet, so they haven't said anything). You write: "They have not lost their status a month after the suspension. [...] Please share your thoughts on the appropriate course of actions." - as written, you're asking about the right course of actions in this particular case.

If you want to ask the general question, rip out the example and ask how it is enforced - I think as long as it's included, there's no way to interpret this question without dragging in that one specific case. Even if the events behind the suspension aren't relevant here, the case itself (and the lacking recognition removal) is, in your current wording of the question

@Zoe I kinda feel you dismissed a whole paragraph prior to me asking about "appropriate course of actions". That said, I do see what you mean. I will make some changes (not quite taking out the example, but trying to put less emphasis on it). Please let me know if that makes it better (maybe not perfect, but better). Thanks.

@RyanM thanks for the edits and insights. I agree that the rules should be clarified. Having a bullet-in for that seems appropriate. However,  on your 2nd point, I am not sure unifying the rules would be easy. For instance, we have discussed that maintaining r-collective RM status requires the RM to be involved in moderation efforts. Other Collectives may not agree with that. So, I think as a compromise we can have some basic rules (e.g. the first 3 bullet points from the SOfT screenshot) shared between every collective. Thoughts?

I mean, or just get rid of collectives
