My comment on SO Meta was deleted. I would like to get the information about it
I remember commenting on one of the recent posts on Meta, but I don't remember the exact question. I tried to find it in my All Activities in the Profile but it is not there. I think it got deleted without me knowing anything about it.
Is there any way for me, the comment maker, to know the information about the deleted comment?
The information in here I mean:

Why was the comment deleted?
When was the comment deleted?
Who deleted the comment?
Which question that the comment got deleted from?
Can I even find the actual comment that got deleted?


Comments may be deleted by moderators or by sufficiently many Community members flagging the comment as "No longer needed"/"Unfriendly/Unkind" or similar. See How does comment voting and flagging work? and When should comments be deleted?

Also comments could be deleted alongside the parent post (the question/answer you commented on).

Who deleted the comment?  Why do you need that info? Are you planning on using your pitch-fork?

Why does it matter if the comment was deleted?

@ThomA Their voice was silenced. Injustice. Burning sensation in the pit of the stomach. A flippant thing of me to say... but not unrealistic. I've felt the burn too.

"Which question that the comment got deleted from?" How do you know a comment got deleted if you don't even know where the alleged comment ought to be?

If the archives are correct, you've only made one comment recently, which was posted on the question How do I eliminate this weird "landing page"? Is it possible? and read:

and today I learned that what we had before was already good.

So to answer the "why"; very likely because it was no longer needed.
This answers your questions, 1, 4 and 5. 2 and 3 likely only a moderator could answer. For 2, why does it matter? It was some time between it being posted and you noticing it was deleted. And 3 doesn't really matter either; It was a moderator, and they acted correctly.
Comments do, and and often are deleted; especially a comment like that which doesn't add anything to the post. Such comments are more likely to be flagged as "No Longer Needed" (NLN), and so a moderator will review and likely delete said comment. I see no foul play here.
If a comment truly is important, and you think it should have long lasting value, post an answer instead.

You can't get any such info, no.
The general policy over the years has been "comments are not important", and so mods can delete them at any moment for whatever the reason and we won't know why. Unless the comment was a CoC violation or something like that, in which case the mods might send you a message.

...which is not ideal on meta, since the Q&A format is pretty hopeless for discussions. Instead of actual discussion, we are encouraged to hold monologues in the form of answers. Threaded comments would solve a lot of that - this is the last place on the Internet without threaded comments.

Note (for completeness) that mods should are probably able to get the deleted comments of users (and I guess they also see how a specific comment was deleted).

They can, @dan1st . I've even seen (in very rare occasions) them undelete a comment; though that doesn't appear to be applicable here.

generally you're right, but to be anal, not in cases like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399562 :D
